# recommendations for implementation of C++ template class in a separate file and IDE support

Tags: c++, templates, ide

Template class implementation needs to be accessible when the template is instantiated in the calling code. Hence the easy solution is to put the class definition and implementation in a single header file. 
There are of course other solutions. The solutions I could find with Google are basically already summarized in http://blog.ethanlim.net/2014/07/separate-c-template-headers-h-and.html
which proposes either:

- All implementation into the header file
- Explicit Template Instantiation in the implementation (*.cpp)

A variant of the first I have seen other persons use and I have used myself is to create a header file for the implementation myTemplateClass_impl.h that is included from the other header myTemplateClass.h.
I always thought it was the recommended way of doing this but searching with Google, I was surprised I could not find this technique described anywhere. Now I have one problem with this technique: it breaks vscode intellisense (or other IDEs C++ support) because the myTemplateClass_impl.h is not self contained.

Now there is a way to make it IDE friendly but it is a bit convoluted:

myTemplateClass.h

```
#ifndef MYTMPCL_H
#define MYTMPCL_H
namespace tmpcl {
  template <typename T> class TmpCL
  {
    ...
  } 
} // namespace tmpcl
#include "myTemplateClass_impl.h"
#endif // MYTMPCL_H
```

myTemplateClass_impl.h

```
#ifndef MYTMPCL_IMPL_H
#define MYTMPCL_IMPL_H
#include "myTemplateClass.h"
namespace tmpcl {
    // implementation
  template <typename T> TmpCL::...

} // namespace tmpcl

#endif // MYTMPCL_IMPL_H
```

Now it does not matter which of the two files is included. They both expand to the same code and vscode intellisense is happy.
Is this design any good?

Thank you.

Also I was surprised I could not find recommendations for how to do this in the C++ core guidelines at https://isocpp.org/

Comment: Why do you want it in a separate file?

Comment: The main .h file is also used by other developers to have look at the interface. They don't want to be exposed to unnecessary details. If they need to, they can still look at the implementation header but otherwise this just adds noise.

Comment: "They don't want to be exposed to unnecessary details. " - nobody is forcing them to look at them - I never look at the implementation of std::string, for example.

Comment: IDE's typically support the implementation of template functions outside of the class definition, with refactoring ("move outside of the class"). So you can maintain the whole class in one file, the class definition at the top and the implementation after the definition. When you open the file you just look at the top of it.
Also IDE's support folding of code sections to reduce the apparent verbosity, so the implementation section could be folded in just a line within the Editor.
I rather would recommend this approach than having two files.